# Error: /snap/core/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found

Tags: javascript, ubuntu

```
Error: /snap/core/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by 
/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/protagonist/build/Release/protagonist.node)
Code: ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED
```

[image: CONSOLE]

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1140183/install-gcc-9-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.